# PBX Outbound Call using TAPI

Tags: at-command, tapi

I need to develop a TAPI application to instruct PBX to make outbound call. Without the application, an user needs to dial 9, then the specified destination phone number to make a call. Otherwise, the user can only make call to other extension.

What should i do to let the TAPI application perform similar action?

```
BSTR ppDialableString;
ppDialableString = "0123456789";

hr = pAddress->CreateCall(
    ppDialableString,
    dwAddressType,
    TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO,
    &pBasicCall
 );

if ( hr != S_OK ) return hr;
```

ppDialableString is the destination number. How should i modify the code segment above to cater for the dial code '9' ?

By the way, the PBX that the application going to communicate with is Panasonic KX-TDA200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

```
BSTR ppDialableString;
ppDialableString = "9,0123456789";
```